# Is there a way to exclude a function before pushing an object into an array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

When I push an object into an array, it pushes the object and it's methods too like makeaction(), but I don't wanna see them inside the array, Is there a way to exclude them

I got this on console

```
[ Pilot {
makeaction: [Function],
_name: 'Michael',
_lstname: 'Kiddies',
_age: 50,
_weight: 80,
_expyear: 8,
vec: 
 Car {
   _price: 3500000,
   _weight: 1300,
   _speed: 360,
   _power: 650,
   _brand: 'Aston Martin',
   _model: 'Vulcan',
   _torque: 1200,
   _person: [Circular] } },
Pilot {
makeaction: [Function],
_name: 'Enzo',
_lstname: 'LaFerrari',
_age: 23,
_weight: 90,
_expyear: 20,
vec: 
 Car {
   _price: 3500000,
   _weight: 1200,
   _speed: 320,
   _power: 750,
   _brand: 'Ferrari',
   _model: 'FXXK',
   _torque: 900,
   _person: [Circular] } },
Pilot {
makeaction: [Function],
_name: 'Austin',
_lstname: 'Texas',
_age: 30,
_weight: 56,
_expyear: 2,
vec: 
 Ship {
   _price: 5000000,
   _weight: 15000,
   _speed: 50,
   _power: 7000,
   _shipname: 'Evelin Mærsk',
   _beam: 20,
   _lenghtov: 55,
   _person: [Circular] } }]
```

Also I Want to delete that `_person: [Circular]` inside the array

These are some of my Classes

**Pilot.ts**

```
 export class Pilot extends Person implements PersonInterface {
    private vec: Vehicle;
    private _expyear: number;

    constructor(name?, lstname?, age?, weight?, expyears?, vec?: Vehicle) {
        super(name, lstname, age, weight);
        this.vec = vec;
        this._expyear = expyears;
        vec.person = this;
    }

    get expyear(): number {
        return this._expyear;
    }

    set expyear(value: number) {
        this._expyear = value;
    }

    public makeaction = () => {
        return this.vec.makeaction();
    }
}
```

**Car.ts**

```
export class Car extends Vehicle {
    private _brand: string;
    private _model: string;
    private _torque: number;

    constructor(brand?, model?, torque?, weight?, speed?, pow?, price?) {
        super(weight, speed, pow, price);
        this._brand = brand;
        this._model = model;
        this._torque = torque;
    }

    get brand(): string {
        return this._brand.trim();
    }

    set brand(value: string) {
        this._brand = value;
    }

    get model(): string {
        return this._model;
    }

    set model(value: string) {
        this._model = value;
    }

    get torque(): number {
        return this._torque;
    }

    set torque(value: number) {
        this._torque = value;
    }

    public makeaction() {
        if (this.person.constructor.name == `Customer`) {
            return `The ${this.person.constructor.name} ${this.person.name} ${this.person.lstname} has bought the ${this.constructor.name} ${this.brand + ` ` + this.model} for only ${prf.convertMillions(this.price)}`;
        }
        else {
            return `The ${this.person.constructor.name} ${this.person.name} ${this.person.lstname} is driving the ${this.constructor.name} ${this.brand + ` ` + this.model}`;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have control over that, you could define the object's methods as non-enumerable with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: also, you shouldn't use arrow functions to define methods on a prototype, because `this` will be bound to the lexical context and not the instance at runtime (`makeaction` in Pilot.ts).

Comment: Add `toJSON` methods to each class and export the fields you need.  Then when adding to an array call `instance.toJSON()`

Comment: "*I don't wanna see them*" - What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Object.defineproperty isn't working on typescript, not even in the transpiled js file, I'am actually using typescript that compiles to ES6 target

Comment: @Bergi see the functions included as property inside the objects of the array

Comment: @AlxMrcer Yes, I can see them, but why would you care about console output when your program is working otherwise?

Comment: I was getting the same problem when I was parsing the array to a json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `public makeaction = () => {`, and the reason why it shows up in the console, is that it is a class property not a prototype method. It's a property created in the constructor and assigned an arrow function. You'll want to make it a normal method:

```
public makeaction() {
    …
```

That way, it's implicitly non-enumerable (in ES6 `class`es at least), and won't be considered by the console pretty printer because it is inherited.

Comment: that worked ty, but, what about to remove `_person: [Circular]`?,I need to get person's name, age, etc

Comment: When the console prints `[Circular]`, you know that the object is already printed elsewhere - in this case just look at the properties of the `Pilot` instance right above.